# How to write a url to another page in webpack2

Tags: webpack-2

I am using `html-webpack-plugin` to generate my html page for entry file. I don't want to care where my page output. It may be difference from source file oganization.

```
src
  a
    a.html
  b
    b.html
```

a.html

```
<a href="what is the b url here?">to b</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. In addition to adding a reference of your bundle to the generated a.html, do you also want generated a.html to refer to b.html.
I would use a top html template which will include a reference to your bundle like index.html.
Then you could use the raw-loader to just copy over a.html and b.html:

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader'],
    exclude: path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
  }
```